# UWP GridView equivalent of WPF DataGrid

Tags: xaml, uwp, datagrid, uwp-xaml

How can we use the UWP's [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview?view=winrt-18362) to look like the following [WPF DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid)?

Remark: The data binding is not important. You can just assume a Pseudo-code (psedo class with attributes MyTableId, DateModified, Author).

**WPF DataGrid XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPFProj.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    ...........
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="103*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="697*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgMathDocs" IsReadOnly="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="0,43,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="btnDelete" Content="Delete" Click="btnDelete_Click"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding MyTableId}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Date Modified">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateModified}"  BorderThickness="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author}"/>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**WPF DataGrid Display of the above XAML**:

[image]

Comment: Hi, why do you insist on using GridView instead of DataGrid? DataGrid provides close to the use of DataGrid in WPF and many special methods. Compared with GridView, DataGrid can obviously achieve your needs faster. You can also refer to the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid) of DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) from [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit).

More information you can find from [Sample App](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp) on GitHub

Comment: I am aware of this toolkit. But I am only interested in using `GridView` control of UWP.